# Oracle Error: 'ORA-00936: missing expression' in an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have seen many other people having problems like this, but none have helped me solve my problem. I am getting an error

> ORA-00936: missing expression

using this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO FINAL_N2_GAS (id, sdate, edate, room, advsr_nm, serial_num, prev_read, curr_read, pressure, order_id, account_num) 
VALUES (CONVERT(NUMBER, 1), TO_DATE(trunc('6/13/2020 12:00:00 AM'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE(trunc('6/14/2020 12:00:00 AM'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '001C', 'Last, First', '00-A00-0000', '0', '221089', '2.13', '35', '100000-00000');
```

The `CREATE TABLE` statement in case that is useful

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_N2_GAS 
(
    id          NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    sdate       DATE NOT NULL,
    edate       DATE NOT NULL,
    room        VARCHAR(25),
    advsr_nm    VARCHAR(25),
    serial_num  VARCHAR(25),
    prev_read   VARCHAR(25),
    curr_read   VARCHAR(25),
    pressure    VARCHAR(15),
    order_id    VARCHAR(10),
    account_num VARCHAR(25)
);
```

I have been staring at this for too long, another set of eyes would be amazing.

Thanks :)

Comment: Oracle say [not to use varchar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E).

Comment: Also, [date literals are written like `date '2020-06-13'`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't have a `convert` function.  You could `cast(1 as number(10))` but there wouldn't seem to be any point to doing so.  Just insert the value 1.  You're calling `trunc` on a string before passing it to `to_date` which doesn't make a lot of sense.  That's going to force an implicit cast of the string to a date which would fail unless you've changed your session's `nls_date_format` to match the format of the string you're specifying.  You probably just want to remove the `trunc` and change the format mask on the `to_date` to match the format of the string you're specifying.

So you likely want something like this, [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=921af0c861770e048972b7f58d5ff734)

```
INSERT INTO FINAL_N2_GAS (id, sdate, edate, 
                          room, advsr_nm, serial_num, prev_read, curr_read, pressure, 
                          order_id, account_num) 
  VALUES (1, TO_DATE('6/13/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('6/14/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
          '001C', 'Last, First', '00-A00-0000', '0', '221089', '2.13', 
          '35', '100000-00000');
```

Practically, it seems unlikely that you really want things like `prev_read`, `curr_read`, or `pressure` to be `varchar` columns.  It seems likely that you'd want to do math on them at some point in which case they really ought to be numbers.  Assuming `order_id` is a numeric value generated from a sequence, it ought to be a number as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reasoning behind casting the id as a number was because I was getting an 'invalid number' error, but I guess that may have been something else (most likely with the date). As far as `prev_read` `curr_read` and `pressure` , I am only displaying them so strings are a bit easier to work with.

Comment: _" I am only displaying them so strings are a bit easier to work with."_ - tables should be designed to the actual data types and relations, not to map directly to a particular query or report.  You may be "only displaying" them now, but when the time comes to manipulate them as numbers (and that is only "when" , not "if") you will find them _much_ more difficult to deal with.  Dealing with NUMBER type for display purposes is trivial.  Dealing with character strings for math is far less trivial.